# Add tr after 4 uploaded images

Tags: php, html, html-table

I want a gallery of uploaded images, showing 4 images each tr.
There needs to be a loop somewhere but I can't get it to work.
 It needs to add a tr automatically when there are 4 images in a tr.

```
<?php
    $folder = 'uploads/';
    $filetype = '*.*';
    $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
    $count = count($files);

    $sortedArray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $sortedArray[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($files[$i]))] = $files[$i];
    }

    krsort($sortedArray);
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($sortedArray as &$filename) {
        echo '<td align="center">';
        echo '<a name="'.$filename.'" href="#'.$filename.'"><img src="'.$filename.'" /></a>';
        echo 'Bestand naam: ' . substr($filename,strlen($folder),strpos($filename, '.')-strlen($folder));
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter in your loop. It should look like this :

```
echo '<table>';
$ctr = 0;
foreach ($sortedArray as &$filename) {
    echo ($ctr % 4 == 0) ? "<tr>" : "";
    echo '<td align="center">';
    echo '<a name="'.$filename.'" href="#'.$filename.'"><img src="'.$filename.'" /></a>';
    echo 'Bestand naam: ' . substr($filename,strlen($folder),strpos($filename, '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '</td>';
    $ctr++;
    echo ($ctr % 4 == 0) ? "</tr>" : "";

}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: thats not it. i get first row 1 then 3 then 1 again

Comment: I noticed, i've put the counter increment in the wrong place that's why. I've updated my answer, try it now please, it looks okay now. [Here's my test.](http://ideone.com/WlREXl)

Comment: Thank you too, please upvote my answer if you think it's useful! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Let a counter, say $i run alongside your foreach loop that ticks up by one every time the loop ran. Check for "every fourth element" with if ($i % 4 ==0)

Comment: can you maby show it in my code. im just starting with PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$folder = 'uploads/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder . $filetype);
$count = count($files);
$sortedArray = array();
$i = 0;
krsort($sortedArray);
echo '<table><tr>';

foreach($sortedArray as & $filename)
{
    echo '<td align="center">';
    echo '<a name="' . $filename . '" href="#' . $filename . '"><img src="' . $filename . '"/> </a>';
    echo 'Bestand naam: ' . substr($filename, strlen($folder) , strpos($filename, '.') - strlen($folder));
    echo '</td>';
    if ($i % 4 == 0)
    {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

    $i++;
}

echo '</tr></table>';
?>
```